# Дерганье кастового tabBar при использовании hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: swift

В UITabBarController изменяю внешний вид.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       
        tabBar.frame.size.width = view.frame.width - Constants.tabBarReduction
        tabBar.frame.size.height = Constants.tabBarHeight
        tabBar.frame.origin.y = view.frame.height - Constants.tabBarYPadding
        tabBar.frame.origin.x = Constants.tabBarReduction / 2
        tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.tabBarReduction
    }
```

при первоначальной загрузке все отображается корректно. Но после возвращения со страницы, где скрывался tabBar

```
        hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

элементы tabBar на секунду смещаются вверх относительно центра и возвращаются обратно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?